# How can I concatenate id to my url in fetch while my route is /task/updateStatus/{id}?

Tags: javascript, laravel, fetch

I set my route to `"Route::patch('/task/updateStatus/{id}', 'TaskController@saveStatusUpdate');"` then on my fetch I set the url into `"/task/updateStatus/{id}"`. shows that "`419 (unknown status)"`. Also I tried to concatenate the ID by `fetch("/task/saveStatusUpdate/" + id)`. But in the console it shows that ID is not defined.

Here's my code for my fetch():

```
function drop(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    let taskCard = document.getElementById(ev.target.id);
    var targetElement = document.getElementById(ev.srcElement.id);
    var dropTarget = targetElement.getAttribute("data-match");
    console.log("ev.srcElement.id =", ev.srcElement.id);

    let valueDrop = targetElement.getAttribute("value");
        taskCard.setAttribute("value", valueDrop);

        let gotTheValue = taskCard.getAttribute("value");
        console.log("the value now of the card " + gotTheValue);
    console.log(taskCard);


    if(droppedElementId == dropTarget){
        // console.log("cardValue=" + )
        console.log("dropTarget=" + dropTarget);
        console.log("droppedElementId=" + droppedElementId);
        // alert("dropTarget =" + dropTarget);
    };      
    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

    let urlUpdate = "/task/saveStatusUpdate/{id}";
    // use of fetch
    fetch(urlUpdate, {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name-csrf="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "status_id": gotTheValue
        })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(console.log)
}
```

Then here's my code for the web.php

```
Route::patch('/task/saveStatusUpdate/{id}', 'TaskController@saveStatusUpdate');
```

I expect that once I drop the card, it will change the value of the status_id on my database. but there are an error says that `"flexi.js:45 PATCH http://localhost:8000/task/saveStatusUpdate/%7Bid%7D 419 (unknown status)" and "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"`

Comment: _"in the console it shows that ID is not defined"_  that would be because you have not defined an `id` variable anywhere

Comment: Replace `let urlUpdate = "/task/saveStatusUpdate/{id}";` with `let urlUpdate = "/task/saveStatusUpdate/" + droppedElementId;`

Answer (score -1):

the problem with

```
 let urlUpdate = "/task/saveStatusUpdate/{id}";
```

should be

```
`/task/saveStatusUpdate/${id}`
```

when use ES6
and the id not defined as you didnot handle any id to be sent
may be the taskCard